# GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date. Requires 5089000 but found 5077534

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

I have a problem with an update to the google-play-services SDK.

My app builds and runs (as it did before) - but on the Android wear watch, this message is in the logs:

> GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 5077534

So the app is compiling with 5.0.89 but the watch only has version 5.0.77.

The communication between the watch and the phone now fails (it had worked previously).

How would I make the app backwards compatible with earlier versions of google-play-services given that Android Studio doesn't provide a way to go back to earlier versions of google-play-services?

These are the gradle settings for the wear app

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
   compile "com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+"
   compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.+"
}
```

If I try and force Android Studio to use version 5.0.77 it complains in the build:

> Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77

How can I remain compatible with watches with earlier versions of Google play services?

Comment: Did you try forcing it to the latest 4.x version ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+')? This worked for me, but maybe features for Android Wear will be missing. Also be careful to change this in all the Gradle files of your app modules having Google Play in its dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build.gradle on the wearable side needs to be updated to use play-services-wearable instead of just play-services like you have shown above.

So if you look at one of the samples like DataLayer provided in the Wear SDK, it uses something like this in wearable/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

I have put in a request to get this mentioned in the official documentation soon.

Comment: What if I encounter the same issue with Eclipse? How should I go about resolving it?

Comment: @Warlax: what did you do to get play-services working on the wearable previously with Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

This happens when your mobile has old play-service and you are using new play-service lib. so all you need to update your google-play-service from your phone.

You can use

```
int googleServiceStatus = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this,googleServiceStatus, 10);
    if(dialog!=null){
        dialog.show();
    }
```

this will show popup in case of any problem to get play-service.